# ios adding a collectionView inside UITableView's header view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've an `UICollectionView` inside the `headerView` of my `UITableView` which is made in other `xib` file (custom view) . So my question is, should I declare delegate methods on the same class I've declared my `tableView` or on the custom view which is header of `tableView`? Which is more convenient?

Comment: A custom view isn't a view controller

Comment: Yeah so how do I declare it in my view controller?

Comment: @thewarri0r9 : I have the similar screen where I have a collectionView in a tableViewCell and I keep the collectionView Delegates in cell which kinda makes sense logically because cell is showing collectionView hence it should be responsible for providing data and handling delegate calls and should not bother viewController for that :) So I would say create delegate and data source in your customView :) Though I must say its just the way u interpret the scenario there is no hard right or wrong approach to it :)

Comment: Initialize your CollectionView from the Nib then simply set its `delegate` and `datasource` with your controller where you are adding tableView, and set collectionView as TableHeaderView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the delegates of UITableView & UICollectionView in same controller, set there delegates to the same class as

```
self.mytableview.delegate = self;
self.mycollectionview.delegate = self;
```

You can follow this tutorial, [Putting a UICollectionView in a UITableViewCell](https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell/)